# Installing ubuntu 19.04 (Desktop & Server) Kernel Panics and Crashes

Tags: boot, server, nvidia, kernel, live-usb

Hey so I have windows 10 installed on my computer and I've been trying to install ubuntu alongside it but it gives me the error detailed in the picture when I run the 19.04 server with safe graphics.

Hardware:

- Intel i9 9900k CPU
- ASUS WS X299 SAGE Motherboard
- Two RTX 2080 Ti GPUs
- An HDD and NVME SSD
- 64 GB of Corsair RAM

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJrLy.jpg)

Comment: I see squashfs read errors, ie. your install-media is corrupt.  Did you check-install-media-for-errors before you tried to install? I suspect not, for had you have done that it would have told you the media was invalid (ie. download or write-to-thumb-drive failed).

Answer (score 0):

You need to verify the ISO, or if it's valid, write it again to thumb-drive or your install media as either of them was flawed as shown by squashfs read errors in your picture.

For information on verifying your install media, please see

https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu

To use the check-media-for-defects option you can see

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck

*though the picture shows a much older release of Ubuntu, but the "Check CD for defects" option is what you needed to use to detect your flaws*

The other options is a bad thumb-drive (or cd/dvd or whatever install media you had), or bad hardware, but I'm betting it'll be download or write-to-thumb-drive that failed.

Answer (score 0):

- check your motherboard BIOS version with `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and then go to the manufacturer's web site and see if there's a newer version.
- check for a firmware update for the NVMe.
- run a memory test. Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run the free `memtest` to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the tests to confirm good memory. This will take many hours to run.